# Xamarin iOS how to get all available SysSound list?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, system-sounds

I'm trying create a list of all available alert sounds given in an iOS device.
In Xamarin's website, there's only one example:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/syssound-example/

I would like to know which additional sounds can I access via my Apple device.

Edit:
How do I get the list of build-in alert sounds

Comment: `SystemSound` is a helper class that wraps `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`, you provide a `NSUrl` to it that points to a sound file. In the example you listed, the only sound file in the project is `Sounds/tap.aif.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there are no other sounds in `SystemSound` unless I put them there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here :

https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/Audio/UISounds

e.g:

```
string NotificationSoundPath = @"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received6.caf";
SystemSound notificationSound = SystemSound.FromFile(NotificationSoundPath);
notificationSound.AddSystemSoundCompletion(SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound);
notificationSound.PlaySystemSound();
```